# Is it possible to refresh the receipt of an in-app subscription from an iTunes API?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I have a backend api that accepts the receipt hash data from client ios devices when an iTunes subscription is purchased. I use `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` to verify the receipt data from Apple and to get the subscription details such as transaction id, expiration date etc.

It seems based on [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46737#136714) post that I need to refresh such receipts to discover whether or not there is a cancellation_date. Other than doing this from an ios device as described in the developer [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW2), is there any other way to call an itunes endpoint from the server-side?

Comment: No, only the app on the device has access to the receipt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the receipt itself and have the server store it.  Then, re-send the receipt from the server as often as needed to check for subscription updates.

[Apple docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW4)

> ## Persisting Using Your Own Server
>
> Send a copy of the receipt to your server along with some kind of credentials or identifier so you can keep track of which receipts belong to a particular user. For example, let users identify themselves to your server with an email or user name, plus a password. Don’t use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice—you can’t use it to identify and restore purchases made by the same user on a different device, because different devices have different values for this property.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW3) for how to validate a receipt on the server side may be helpful here as well.